# Android is not appear in panel in windows(preferences)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi im new to android development. I cant launch android project i think i missed out something but i cant get where i did mistake in installing. i briefly explain what i did.

1) download Sdk package from [**http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html**](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and i run the sdk manager . and installed by checking it. i put android-sdk-windows folder in eclipse.

2) then i followed this link [http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing.)

3)Then i called ADT plugin zip windows-->preferences -->instal software sites.... i download adt plugin 17.zip

4) but still i cant find android in windows (preference) in left side  of panel.

Im sorry if u feel my question is stupid or silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You often need to restart Eclipse after adding a new plugin/extension; try that and then see if the Android preferences appear in the preference panel.

Comment: yeah didit. no use. plan to get eclipse + androidsdk as a one file from my friends